# Sort in ascending and descending column by defined blocks of rows

Tags: awk

I am trying to sort column 2 considering blocks of 5 rows all time.
E.g.
**First block rows 1 to 5** : Sort column 2 in ascending order
**Second block rows 6 to 10** : Sort column 2 in descending order

Do this operation in all file

**Input file**

```
P 45683.00  39785.00 1 12 
P 45685.00  39785.00 1 12 
P 45687.00  39785.00 1 12 
P 45689.00  39785.00 1 12 
P 45691.00  39785.00 1 12 
P 45683.00  39795.00 1 12 
P 45685.00  39795.00 1 12 
P 45687.00  39795.00 1 12 
P 45689.00  39795.00 1 12 
P 45691.00  39795.00 1 12 
P 45683.00  39805.00 1 12 
P 45685.00  39805.00 1 12 
P 45687.00  39805.00 1 12 
P 45689.00  39805.00 1 12 
P 45691.00  39805.00 1 12 
P 45683.00  39815.00 1 12 
P 45685.00  39815.00 1 12 
P 45687.00  39815.00 1 12 
P 45689.00  39815.00 1 12 
P 45691.00  39815.00 1 12
```

**desired output**

```
P 45683.00  39785.00 1 12 
P 45685.00  39785.00 1 12 
P 45687.00  39785.00 1 12 
P 45689.00  39785.00 1 12 
P 45691.00  39785.00 1 12 
P 45691.00  39795.00 1 12 
P 45689.00  39795.00 1 12 
P 45687.00  39795.00 1 12 
P 45685.00  39795.00 1 12 
P 45683.00  39795.00 1 12 
P 45683.00  39805.00 1 12 
P 45685.00  39805.00 1 12 
P 45687.00  39805.00 1 12 
P 45689.00  39805.00 1 12 
P 45691.00  39805.00 1 12 
P 45691.00  39815.00 1 12 
P 45689.00  39815.00 1 12 
P 45687.00  39815.00 1 12 
P 45685.00  39815.00 1 12 
P 45683.00  39815.00 1 12
```

**attempts**

```
awk '/45691.00/{"awk \\$0+0==\\$0 "file | getline x}
{print x"~"FNR"~"$0 | "sort -k2,2n "}'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you REALLY trying to sort every 5 lines or trying to sort every time $3 changes and that just happens to be every 5 lines in your current data set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU awk for [sorted_in](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ block[$2] = block[$2] $0 ORS }
!(NR % 5) { prt() }
END { prt() }

function prt(   i,j) {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_" ( (++inst) % 2 ? "asc" : "desc" )
    for (i in block) {
        printf "%s", block[i]
    }
    delete block
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
P 45683.00  39785.00 1 12
P 45685.00  39785.00 1 12
P 45687.00  39785.00 1 12
P 45689.00  39785.00 1 12
P 45691.00  39785.00 1 12
P 45691.00  39795.00 1 12
P 45689.00  39795.00 1 12
P 45687.00  39795.00 1 12
P 45685.00  39795.00 1 12
P 45683.00  39795.00 1 12
P 45683.00  39805.00 1 12
P 45685.00  39805.00 1 12
P 45687.00  39805.00 1 12
P 45689.00  39805.00 1 12
P 45691.00  39805.00 1 12
P 45691.00  39815.00 1 12
P 45689.00  39815.00 1 12
P 45687.00  39815.00 1 12
P 45685.00  39815.00 1 12
P 45683.00  39815.00 1 12
```

If you actually want to print every time `$3` changes instead of every 5 lines then just change:

```
{ block[$2] = block[$2] $0 ORS }
!(NR % 5) { prt() }
```

to:

```
$3 != prev { prt(); prev=$3 }
{ block[$2] = block[$2] $0 ORS }
```

Comment: Yeah, it's literally been years since I used `asort()` or `asorti()`. As soon as `sorted_in` was introduced in gawk 4.0 (we're on gawk 5.0.1 now so it's been a wile!) it was like a breath of fresh air since, to me at least, it's far easier and more intuitive to use than either of those functions.

Comment: I don't understand how those functions feel so unintuitive. Gotta google them every time I use them.

Comment: idk, but I always had to look up the man page and read it about 5 times before I could write the code to use either of them. There's an index here and it becomes a value there and there's this other array created which when you loop through the indices has entries for values that are the indices of the original array... and if you call this function on that array you lose the original indices and get other indices - my head was always spinning trying to figure out which function to call when and then piece together the outcomes.

Comment: Earlier today I was `a[NR%5]=$0; asort(a...)` and the size of `a[]` just kept growing. :D

Comment: At first I thought that sounded like a bug but it makes sense since every time you're populating it with indices 0-4 but after sorting it has indices 1-5 and then on a next assignment you add a 0 to get 0-5 and then asort produces 1-6, etc. Again, not exactly intuitive!

Comment: Yup, that's what happened. :D God damned flu. :D :D

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk and `asort()`:

```
$ gawk '
function process() {
    asort(a,a,(o=="@ind_num_asc" ? o="@ind_num_desc" : o="@ind_num_asc"))
    for(i in a)
        print a[i]
    delete a
}
{
    a[$2]=a[$2] (a[$2]==""?"":ORS) $0
}
NR%5==0 {
    process()
}
END {
    process()
}' file
```

Output:

```
P 45683.00  39785.00 1 12 
P 45685.00  39785.00 1 12 
P 45687.00  39785.00 1 12 
P 45689.00  39785.00 1 12 
P 45691.00  39785.00 1 12 
P 45691.00  39795.00 1 12 
P 45689.00  39795.00 1 12 
P 45687.00  39795.00 1 12 
P 45685.00  39795.00 1 12 
P 45683.00  39795.00 1 12 
P 45683.00  39805.00 1 12 
P 45685.00  39805.00 1 12 
P 45687.00  39805.00 1 12 
P 45689.00  39805.00 1 12 
P 45691.00  39805.00 1 12 
P 45691.00  39815.00 1 12
P 45689.00  39815.00 1 12 
P 45687.00  39815.00 1 12 
P 45685.00  39815.00 1 12 
P 45683.00  39815.00 1 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sample input file has the following characteristics:

- The lines 1-5,11-15,... are already sorted
- The lines 6-10,16-20,... are upsidedown

If this is the case, then the following (totally ugly and non reusable, ahahah) command should be enough:

```
< file1 sed -E 'N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;s/^(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)$/\1\n\6\n\5\n\4\n\3\n\2/' > file2.out
```